# How to Stop NSOutlineView background transparent

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a NSOutlineview at the top and below is a custom view in one window. I want to change color of this custom view to have the same color with the NSOutlineview.

However, I can't seem to do that since the NSOutlineView's background color seems to be gray but it also transparent make its color different if there is other app window beneath it.

How should i do to have NSOutlineview and my custom view same color?